# What to do with images containing URLs / adverts

Tags: discussion, spam, images, advertising

...like [this one](https://superuser.com/a/922272/156554) (screenshot including *WindowClippings.com* reference).

What to with such stuff:

- nothing, ignore (really?),
- downvote (giving negative score to otherwise good answer only because of screenshot, really?),
- flag (how, with what flag?),
- edit, download image, crop it, upload (am I allowed to do so as per license here?),
- *something else*?

For me this is an obvious SPAM / advert and should be IMHO punished really painfully (how?)! But, as always, I may be wrong.

**EDIT**: [This](https://superuser.com/a/922272/156554) was **just an example**! The question remains. What should I do, if I find a screenshot tagged with some URL, that is not comming from a screen-grabbing software? Please, read the question title again. There is nothing about screen-grabbers or particular example there.

Comment: So, the user who posted the image is affiliated with WindowClippings.com? A large number of their posts include that, and are irrelevant to the question? Is the OP overtly promoting it?

Comment: `The trial version includes a full copy of Window Clippings, but running it without a license produces screenshots with a watermark. `  Perhaps they are simply using the [trial version](http://windowclippings.com/) (egad! I linked to it!) of the software?

Comment: @Andy I'm custom flagging that as SPAM :P

Comment: Following your logic, 99.999999999% of the images are SPAM

Comment: @ShadowWizard Basing on what?

Comment: @Andy I'm using `Ctrl+PrtSc` for making screenshots for past 20 years. The idea of using 3rd party software, _shareware_, for this purpose somehow slipped my mind. The idea of _creating_ a software to replace `Ctrl+PrtSc` and make it _shareware_, tagging this screenshots sounds like madness to me...

Comment: I'll take two examples from the same question. [This picture](https://i.imgur.com/yxNbNOU.png) is SPAM because it advertise Windows. How rude. [This one](http://i.stack.imgur.com/xqIHK.jpg) is clear SPAM of GWX.exe which little digging reveals as nothing less than "...part of Microsoft advertising program" - spammer should be nuked on spot.

Comment: I have noticed a legit case of user promoting his site in this manner before and a mod took care of it. This is not such a case. I say we don't allow any images at all, b.c who knows what subliminal messaging is in them! For example, I put opacity like 12% or something of a green checkmark in one of my old user profile pics and no one ever consciously noticed it/said anything about it.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Well, it is up to you, how you understand "advert" in my question. If like that, then you're correct, that all images are SPAM here. I used the "URL" string in my question and only added "advert" as an addition. Any of your examples does not include URL and there aren't many in entire SE, that does it. That's why your comment surprised me. And you certainly miss "my logic" in it. And, again -- as per my edit -- maybe I missed an example, but question remains (unaswered): what to do, if someone posts image with clearly a SPAM-like URL. Can I edit image itself and get rid of it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This doesn't appear to be spam. It appears to be a user that is using the unlicensed trial version of the software.

> The trial version includes a full copy of Window Clippings, but running it without a license produces screenshots with a watermark. Once your license key has been entered into Window Clippings you will be ready to take beautiful screenshots for your website, blog, documentation, book project, or whatever your needs may be. - [WindowClippings.com](http://windowclippings.com/)

The answer looks valid. It just happens to include an image (not a direct click able link) to a paid product. I would choose the "nothing, ignore" option here.